# Incremental number in RegEx

Tags: regex

I'm using Bulk Image Downloader to download whole images in a forum thread.

But I need the regular expression to identify the page number increments.

The URL string of the page is this:

**/topic/2244447/+(page number goes here)**

Here's the situation, the page numbers are incremented by +20. So the second page URL is **/topic/2244447/+20** and third page is **/topic/2244447/+40** and so on.

How can I put the regex for this?

Comment: What have you tried? Where do you have trouble? The regex for this is dead simple...

Comment: regex for what exactly? `/(\+\d*[02468]0)?$`...

Comment: Bulk Image Downloader needs a regex to identify page numbers. So yeah, thanks it did work :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `+` will not exist anywhere else, then this should work although it will match any number with any number of digits after the `+`.

`\+\d+`

Answer (score 3):

`\/topic\/2244447\/\+([0-9]*[02468])?0$`

Just being careful:

- I took a look at the documentation, page 28 of the [Bulk Image Downloader user's guide](http://bulkimagedownloader.com/bid-user%27s-guide/bid-user-guide/).
- I wonder whether your page numbers end with 0 or 1.

Comment: `/` is not a special character in regex - only needs to be escaped if inside a `/regex literal/`

Comment: @deathApril If the world were consistent, yes, but the documentation that I linked says otherwise.